# Mousetrap.bind is not working when field is in focus?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, keyboard-shortcuts, mousetrap

I am using Mousetrap for create keyboard shortcuts, it was not working when any fields in focus. This is the link for view demo http://davidwalsh.name/keyboard-shortcuts from where i get the code. when i use to call

```
Mousetrap.bind('ctrl+m', function () {
    var button = $('[data-action="next-page"]');
    if (button.length) {
        button[0].click()
    }
});
```

like this it not working , when mouse points in text-box or drop-down etc,. Can any give solution for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30):

By default mousetrap disable the shortcuts when the focus is on input fields, dropdown, etc..
If your problem is with only one field, include the class `mousetrap` in it.
If you want to disable all scenarios try the following code

```
Mousetrap.stopCallback = function () {
     return false;
}
```

This will overwrite the initial behavior and allow shortcuts in any field of the screen.

Comment: as of v1.5.0, you need to make that Mousetrap.prototype.stopCallback = { ... }

Comment: I had an old additional script that used Mousetrap.stopCallback. Thanks! adding the prototype fixed my problem @jedierikb

Answer (score 2):

If you're using input or textarea or select elements, you must define the mousetrap class:

```
<textarea name="message" class="mousetrap"></textarea>
```

See the "Text fields" section in the oficial doc at https://craig.is/killing/mice